# Plural of irregular or foreign acronyms

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms, loanwords, irregular

What is the correct way of pluralizing acronyms in which the last word is either irregular or a foreign word?

For example: *radiation transparent medium* (RTM)

What would be the plural of the acronym RTM?
RTMs or RTM considering that the plural of *medium* is *media*?

Comment: @Laurel Well found. I was wallowing.

Comment: Please note thet RTM is not _generally_ (on ELU or elsewhere) seen as being an acronym (as the letters are enunciated separately) but as an _initialism_. NATO and radar are seen as acronyms. Check in various dictionaries. However, pluralisation rules are virtually identical. Treat as a new unit: RTMs.